# How to customize XFCE screenshot saving file name template?

Tags: xfce, screenshot

When I press <kbd>Print Scrn</kbd> in XFCE and choose to save it, the automatically generated and offered file name is like `Screenshot - 141012 - 02:21:10.png` (`Screenshot - DDMMYY - HH:mm:SS.png`).

I hate to use Windows-incompatible characters (like `:`) and sorting-unfriendly date formats in file names and moreover the name looks too long: `scrnYYYYMMDDHHmmSS.png` would be much better.

Is it possible to set-up?

Comment: What about writing a function or script that invokes this utility, then looks for the file and changes the file name? Although it would require some work, if you rebind the key on top of that, you get exactly what you want.

Comment: That would be an ugly "crutch", @emanuel-berg. I'd rather modify the source code itself and rebuild the application as warl0ck suggests.

Comment: I wouldn't call it ugly, but sure, rebuilding is certainly an option, and I'm not telling you what to do :) But, when you're done, post your solution, could be interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, it's impossible.

[image]

Manually modify the source code would work for you, but you could submit a bug report for it.
(e.g make this configurable through xfce4-settings)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old thread but as it is top referenced in google,
I post my solution in case somebody else has the same problematic.

It's a simple script using `gimp` script-fu.

There is an argument $1 to define screenshot-mode (-s/-w/-f).

```
#!/bin/sh

filename=`date +"$HOME/Pictures/scrn%Y%m%d%H%M%S.png"`
xfce4-screenshooter -o "gimp -n -a -s -d -f -i -b \ 
   '(gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE 1 2 \"$filename\" \"$filename\")' \
   -b '(gimp-quit 0)'" $1
```

Little annoyance is that on my labtop, it takes at least 2s for gimp to create the png file, so don't forget to insert a sleep command if you want to work the script further.

Dr.Douvron

Answer (score 0):

Another approach based on Dr. Douvron's answer using `cat` instead of `gimp`:

```
target=~/screenshots

mkdir -p $target

filename=$(date +scrn%Y%m%d%H%M%S.png)
path=$target/$filename

xfce4-screenshooter -w -o cat > $path
```

E.g.: https://github.com/felixhummel/bin/blob/master/screenshot-full-auto